# Using new UI Image component to show a image on web in Unity 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to use the new UI objects in Unity 4.6 to create a ranking screen where I download information about the users and show them. Among those informations I have an URL pointing to their picture.

Before the UI tools I was doing it with GUITexture and using the www.LoadImageIntoTexture method, but there doesn't seem to be a similar solution for UI Images. Using a GUITexture with a Rect Transform doesn't seem to work.

Should I just manually download the image and load it into the image or is there a similiar solution as with using WWW class?

Answer (score 9):

The new Image component takes requires a sprite to render.
What should work is download a PNG texture using the WWW class, then creating a sprite and finally assigning it to the component.

Here's some sample code.

1. Create a new Monobehaviour, paste below code into it (I called my script "LoadImageToButton")
2. Create a new UIButton
3. Attach the Monobehaviour created in Step 1 to the Button
4. In the Button's "OnClick" event, Drag the button created in Step 2 (this same button) into the GameObject field
5. Select the "LoadImage" function as the function to call for the OnClick event. (In my case it was "LoadImageToButton.LoadImage")
6. Hit Play, click the button. You should see the button's image change (It looks terrible, but it works)

See the pictures attached for actual results.

```
    //This is the method you call if you use the "OnClick" event from a button click.
    //We cannot call the Coroutine function below, because it breaks the rule for
    //the event system. i.e. Must be a return type of void.

    public void LoadImage () {
        //Call the actual loading method
        StartCoroutine(RealLoadImage());
    }


    //This is where the actual code is executed
    private IEnumerator RealLoadImage () {

        //A URL where the image is stored
        string url = "http://www.axsu3d.com/DLs/AxSWP8Plugin/TileLogo.png";  

        //Call the WWW class constructor
        WWW imageURLWWW = new WWW(url);  

        //Wait for the download
        yield return imageURLWWW;        

        //Simple check to see if there's indeed a texture available
        if(imageURLWWW.texture != null) {

            //Construct a new Sprite
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite();     

            //Create a new sprite using the Texture2D from the url. 
            //Note that the 400 parameter is the width and height. 
            //Adjust accordingly
            sprite = Sprite.Create(imageURLWWW.texture, new Rect(0, 0, 400, 400), Vector2.zero);  

            //Assign the sprite to the Image Component
            GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>().sprite = sprite;  
        }

        yield return null;
    }
```

[image: Before clicking the button. Note the "OnClick" event & the Monobehaviour attached]


[image: After the download and change of sprite. Sprite looks terrible, but it works]

Comment: new Sprite() and then Sprite.Create() is that redundant or do you really need it?

Comment: It's redundant. There more for the comment than actual need.